# Install jitsi from PPAs?

Tags: ppa, instant-messaging

I cannot find the PPA sources for the voice/video and instant messenger chat [jitsi](http://jitsi.org).

How do I install it with apt?

```
apt-get install jitsi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Note:

**You SHOULD NOT manually add Jitsi to your sources list because that would cause GPG Error Warnings! The Jitsi installation would automatically update your repositories.**

Instead just [download the Ubuntu .deb package](https://jitsi.org/Main/Download), that will add the correct GPG Keys for you.
see: https://jitsi.org/Main/DebianRepository

If you still want to do it manually, you would have to add a file in

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jitsi.list
```

with the content

```
deb http://download.jitsi.org/deb unstable/
```

Then you can install it with apt:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install jitsi
```

Comment: **which** .deb package?

Comment: follow my download link and select the "Debian packages"

Comment: there are probably 100 files here:  http://download.jitsi.org/deb/binary/ which one is "the" deb package?  Some of the packages there require other listed packages -- a bit circular in my experience.

Comment: Ah, I see, use the one fitting to your system at the bottom, in the form `jitsi_VERSION_ARCHITECTURE***` (currently for intel 64bit: `jitsi_2.8.5426-1_amd64.deb`)

Answer (score 0):

Jitsi can be easily installed by adding official jitsi repository:
Run the following commands:

```
wget -qO - https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi-key.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb https://download.jitsi.org stable/' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jitsi-stable.list"

sudo apt update -y
```

Install Jitsi Meet

```
sudo apt install -y jitsi-meet
```

Answer (score -1):

It's in the `Ubuntu Software Centre`, and you can easily install it from there.

Comment: Since when? And is it the latest version?

Comment: I don't know, but I downloaded it from there